# How to get a snapshot of a Jira filter in Wiki

Tags: jira, wiki

I am presenting Jira Filters as tables in Wiki (Atlassian). This is a live link.

Is it possible to get a point in time snapshot (not a live link), say every Friday, in Wiki table. I want something in Wiki itself that my team can comment on Wiki page but it does not refresh the Jira content after freeze date/time.

I know there is pdf and doc export options but I want something in the Wiki itself.